# Writed java file server. Somehow client can't do more than 1 operation

Tags: java, serversocket

Idk am i right or not, but i think the problem is that i have to clear data array every iteration, but it doesnt work. At some point i've thought it might be other problem, but i dont know.
at every second operation there is
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: A program on your host machine terminated the established connection

I tried to fix it with Arrays.fill, data = null etc. Tried to do a method that generates byte array and reads the data, unsuccesfully.

here's Server

```
package FileServer;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Server {

    static String path = "D:\\JavaFiles\\data\\";
    private static boolean isRunning = true;
    private static final int PORT = 34522;
    public static HashMap<String, String> filenames = new HashMap<String, String>();



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        createDirectory(path);

        try (ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT)) {
            System.out.println("Server started");

            while (isRunning) {
                String response = "";
                String id = "";
                try (
                        Socket socket = server.accept();
                        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())
                ) {
                    String message = input.readUTF();
                    if (message.equals("exit")) {
                        input.close();
                        output.close();
                        socket.close();
                        isRunning = false;
                    } else{
                        switch ((message.split(";")[0])){

                            case "PUT":
                                System.out.println(message);
                                if (message.split(";").length > 1) {
                                    path = path + message.split(";")[1];
                                }
                                File f = new File(path);
                                if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
                                    response = "403";
                                } else {
                                    int length = input.readInt();
                                    byte[] data = new byte[length];
                                    input.readFully(data, 0, data.length);
                                    System.out.println(path);
                                    String hash = generateId(path);
                                    filenames.put(hash, path);
                                    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path)) {
                                        fos.write(data);
                                        System.out.println(path + "****");
                                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    id = hash;
                                    response = "200" + " " + id;
                                }
                                output.writeUTF(response);
                                path = path.replace(message.split(";")[1],"");
                                break;


                            case "GET":
                                if (message.split(";")[1].equals("n")) {
                                    path = path + message.split(";")[2];
                                    f = new File(path);
                                    if (f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
                                        response = "200";
                                        Path path2 = Paths.get(path);
                                        byte[] data = new byte[0];
                                        if (Files.exists(path2) && !Files.isDirectory(path2)) {
                                            try {
                                                data = Files.readAllBytes(path2);
                                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }
                                        output.writeUTF(response);
                                        output.writeInt(data.length);
                                        output.write(data);
                                    } else {
                                        response = "403";
                                        output.writeUTF(response);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    id = message.split(";")[2];
                                    if (filenames.containsKey(id)) path = filenames.get(id);
                                    f = new File(path);
                                    if (f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
                                        response = "200";
                                        Path path2 = Paths.get(path);
                                        byte[] data = new byte[0];
                                        if (Files.exists(path2) && !Files.isDirectory(path2)) {
                                            try {
                                                data = Files.readAllBytes(path2);
                                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }
                                        output.writeUTF(response);
                                        output.writeInt(data.length);
                                        output.write(data);
                                    } else {
                                        response = "403";
                                        output.writeUTF(response);
                                    }
                                }
                                path = path.replace(message.split(";")[2],"");
                                break;


                            case "DELETE":
                                if (message.split(";")[1].equals("n")){
                                    path = path + message.split(";")[2];
                                } else {
                                    id = message.split(";")[2];
                                    if (filenames.containsKey(id)) path = filenames.get(id);
                                }
                                f = new File(path);
                                if (f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
                                    response = "200";
                                    delete(path);
                                    filenames.remove(path);
                                } else {
                                    response = "403";
                                }
                                output.writeUTF(response);
                                path = path.replace(message.split(";")[2],"");
                                break;
                        }
                        output.flush();
                    }



                }
            }
        }

    }
    public static void createDirectory(String path) {
        File fileDirectory = new File(path);
        if (!fileDirectory.exists()) {
            fileDirectory.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    public static String generateId(String filename) {
        return String.valueOf(Math.abs(filename.hashCode()));
    }

    public static void delete(String filepath) {
        try {
            File file = new File(filepath);
            file.delete();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Here's Client

```
package FileServer;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {

    private static boolean isRunning = true;
    public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SocketException {
        String address = "127.0.0.1";
        int port = 34522;
        Socket socket = new Socket(address,port);
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        String req = "";
        String response = "";
        byte[] data;
        String filename = "";

        while (isRunning) {
            System.out.println("Enter action (1 - get a file, 2 - save a file, 3 - delete a file, exit): ");
            String action = scan.nextLine();
            switch (action) {
                case "1":
                    req = getRequest();
                    output.writeUTF(req);
                    System.out.println("The request was sent.");
                    response = input.readUTF();
                    if (processResponse(response, action)) {
                        int length = input.readInt();
                        data = new byte[length];
                        input.readFully(data, 0, data.length);
                        filename = "D:\\JavaFiles\\data\\" + scan.nextLine();
                        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename)) {
                            fos.write(data);
                            System.out.println(filename + "****");
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        System.out.print("File saved on the hard drive!");
                    }
                    break;

                case "2":
                    System.out.print("Enter filename: ");
                    String name = scan.nextLine();
                    Path path = Paths.get("D:\\JavaFiles\\data\\" + name);
                    data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
                    System.out.print("Enter name of the file to be saved on server: ");
                    String outName = scan.nextLine();
                    output.writeUTF("PUT" + ";" + outName);
                    output.writeInt(data.length); // write length of the message
                    output.write(data);
                    response = input.readUTF();
                    processResponse(response, action);
                    String pathUpdate = path.getParent().toString();
                    path = Path.of(pathUpdate);
                    break;

                case "3":
                    req = deleteRequest();
                    output.writeUTF(req);
                    System.out.println("The request was sent.");
                    response = input.readUTF();
                    processResponse(response, action);
                    break;
                case "exit":
                    output.writeUTF("exit");
                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                    input.close();
                    socket.close();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }





    public static String getRequest() {
        String name = "";
        String mode = "";
        System.out.println("Do you want to get the file by/id (1 - name, 2 - id): ");
        String choice = scan.nextLine();
        switch (choice) {
            case "1":
                System.out.print("Enter filename: ");
                name = scan.nextLine();
                mode = "n";
                break;
            case "2":
                System.out.print("Enter id: ");
                name = scan.nextLine();
                mode = "i";
                break;
        }
        return "GET" + ";" + mode + ";" + name;
    }

    public static String deleteRequest() {
        String name = "";
        String mode = "";
        System.out.println("Do you want to delete the file by name/id (1 - name, 2 - id): ");
        String choice = scan.nextLine();
        switch (choice) {
            case "1":
                System.out.print("Enter filename: ");
                name = scan.nextLine();
                mode = "n";
                break;
            case "2":
                System.out.print("Enter id: ");
                name = scan.nextLine();
                mode = "i";
                break;
        }
        return "DELETE" + ";" + mode + ";" + name;
    }


    public static Boolean processResponse(String response, String operation) {
        switch (operation) {
            case "2":
                if (response.startsWith("200")) {
                    System.out.println("Response says that file is saved! ID = " + response.substring(4));
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("The response says that creating the file was forbidden!");
                }
                break;
            case "1":
                if (response.equals("200"))  {
                    System.out.print("The file was downloaded! Specify a name for it: ");
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("The response says that this file is not found!");
                }
                break;
            case "3":
                if (response.equals("200")) {
                    System.out.println("The response says that the file was successfully deleted!");
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("The response says that this file is not found!");
                }
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

P.s sorry if I wrote my problem poorly, or it is too easy for your great minds. This is my first question on sof, i'm still learning.

Comment: `The Java™ Tutorials -> Writing the Server Side of a Socket`  (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html)  -> `Supporting Multiple Clients`

Comment: Solved a problem finally, noticed that bc of my inattention i put while cycle under try-catch block